# Waveform for audio file in magento

Tags: json, magento, audio

My file is already save. I have file name and file url. for generate waveform i want this type of code.

```
 [0.75827,0.502991,0.765717,0.68399,0.798004,.....]
```

i think this is json of audio file. how can i get this type of json of audio file

Comment: unclear what you're asking: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to create waveform of audio file to create waveform i need this type of json so how to do this

Comment: Still unclear what you have and what you want. You've uploaded a audio file in Magento and you'd like to get some audio information from it? Are you using some module for this or?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to create an array of numbers based on an audiofile to represent the contents of your audio file. You should probably just check the answer on this question which seem to work just fine for that:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381243/how-does-soundcloud-com-generate-the-waveform-for-their-mp3-player

They mention this project does the job (to generate the waveform):
https://github.com/afreiday/php-waveform-png

If you specifically want the array of numbers, you can change the code to store or return the variable $v from this line:

```
$v = (int) ($data / 255 * $height);
```

From: 
https://github.com/afreiday/php-waveform-png/blob/master/php-waveform-png.php